# Where to write my startup method in WPF user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

In a WPF Window Application, I can override `OnStartup` method to add my own logic when the app is launched.

My my app is a add-on of another app, actually, its a `UserControl`.
Where to add my own logic to the app when the app is launched?

Now, I write the code in code behind. Is there a more sensible place to do that?

Comment: What kind of startup logic you want to write? If it is something related to business/data logic better have it in the ViewModel.

Comment: Such as creating some folders which used by my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just trying to define startup logic for a `UserControl`?

Then it depends what you're trying to initialize:

- **Are you trying to initialize all sorts of UI-related data?**

The best solution would be either in the constructor, or in the `Loaded` event in code behind

- **Are you trying to initialize the underlying data for its ViewModel?**

Then you should create it when you call the `UserControl` from your parent app. It should initialize your `ViewModel` and its data, and ilnk it to the `UserControl` you're trying to load

Should be enough to get you started!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my app, I need to check if some folders have exist, if not, create them.

Comment: Definitely ViewModel side then. Keep in mind that the code behind should only have UI-related stuff, and for other things, there is a ViewModel